# Detecting face like patterns using CNN based face detector

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, object-detection, pattern-recognition

I have a CNN-based object detector trained on WIDER Face data set. It can successfully detect human faces in a given image.

Now, I am trying to detect abstract faces and minimalist face patterns in clouds, houses, etc., but having no success.

Initially, I thought neural-network-based object detectors would generalize somehow, and I could lower the detection threshold to detect such patterns, but such a scheme didn't work.

Is there any way other than collecting and labeling such training examples (face-like patterns) to solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.

Answer (score 0):

The stated problem is too broad.  What effect or criteria do you have for "minimalistic [sic] face patterns"?  What defines a face -- certain features in certain spatial relation to one another?  You'll need to determine a good starting point for describing the features and the relationships.

You did well enough with your one experiment -- relaxing the recognition threshold -- but you've discovered that your trained model has criteria that differ from yours.

I recommend that you work on determining your criteria.  If you can't provide clear criteria, you may well have to collect and label specific examples.  You may have to do this even if you *do* specify criteria, but having those specs may lead you to a smaller and clearer set of training cases.

You can also write your own recognition methods and include them in the model code.